Show that $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ with the norm 2 of matrices is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with norm of vectors $|.|_{2}$
Show that $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ with the norm 2 of matrices is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ with norm of vectors $|.|_{2}$
I'm struggling with the question itself. What does it even mean?
I know that the space of linear functionals $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R^2})$ is isomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$. But what is be "isomorphic with the norm"? Do I have to show a function which preserves the norm?
Another question I have is: How to represent a function in $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R^2})$ with a matrix?
My Attempt:
I think a function $f \in \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R^2})$ can be represented as:
$$f = \begin{bmatrix} a & b\end{bmatrix}$$
Its norm 2 would be: $|f| = \sqrt{\rho(A^{T}A)} = \dots = \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}$
Where $\rho(A^{T}A)$ means the maximum eigenvalue of $A^{T}A$
What I do now? Should I take a function which maps the image of the application of the norm 2 of matrices in the $\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R^2})$ into the $\mathbb{R}^2$
///////
Edit:
This is my last attempt
Take this function $F : \mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2) \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, where
$$F(f) = [a, b] \ \ \text{where} \ \ fe_1 = a , \ fe_2 = b$$
Where $e_1, e_2$ are the canbonical vectors de $\mathbb{R}^2$
We have the function $F$ being a bijection, so the spaces are isomorfic. We have to show that the spaces are isomorfic with the norm:
By norm definition we have:
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \|f\|_{2} &=& \max_{\|\mathbf{u}\|_2 = 1} {\|fu\|_2} \\
              &=& \max_{\|\mathbf{u}\|_2 = 1} {\sqrt{(ax + by)^2}}
\end{eqnarray*}
Where $u = [x, y]$. We have to find the vector $u$ which maximizes $\sqrt{(ax + by)^2}$.
Let
$$u =   \begin{bmatrix}
            \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \\[2ex]
            \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}}
        \end{bmatrix}$$
Matricial norm 2 of  $f$ is:
\begin{eqnarray*}
    \|f\|_2 &=& \sqrt{\left( \frac{a^2 + b^2}{\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}} \right)^2} \\
            &=& \sqrt{a^2 + b^2}
\end{eqnarray*}
Which is the norm of the vector $[a, b]$.
To end this solution, we must show that the vector $u$ choosen bring us the maximum value. (I won't do this here).

Also: it's best practice to always include the question in the body of the post.  Separating it into the title makes an extra unnecessary step of connecting the two fields.  It's also probably better for searchability.


But what is be "isomorphic with the norm"?

What you wrote doesn't say "isomorphic with the norm," it says

($\mathcal{L}(\mathbb{R}^2)$ with the norm 2 of matrices) is isomorphic to ($\mathbb{R}^2$ with norm of vectors $|.|_{2}$)

That is, you're talking about two structures (normed linear spaces) that (in principle) may or may not be isomorphic as normed linear spaces.
As you suspected, you'd need to justify that there's a linear isomorphism that's also norm-preserving.

Man. I am still struggling with this. Do you have a book, webpage, anything to help me?

@EduardoAlves uhh, ok, wikipedia?  What question remains?

Sorry for my absence for 8 days. I think I have now come up with a correct solution. I did not represent the function  f as a matrix. My professor told me that doing so would create another isomorphism; he did not want the answer that way.
